# Parallel Processing with Dask Arrays

Tags: parallel-processing, dask

I'm new to Dask and Parallel processing.  I have several hdf5 files and I hope to run each through a function that produces a numerical output.  Within the function, the hdf5 is turned into a dask array.  I was wondering what would be the fastest method to parallelize the code so that each hdf5 file can run through the function at the same time.  Should I be converting the hdf5 files into dask arrays outside of the function?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit abstract but you can load the data using the `read_hdf` method of `dask.dataframe`.

Then do the required computations on it with your function (using `apply` or `map_partitions` or `applymap`).
you can later convert to arrays.

note that you can read several `hdf` files at once using this syntax:

`dd.read_hdf('myfile.*.hdf5', '/x')`

more info:

> http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_hdf

Comment: Are the "apply", "map_paritions" pr "applymap" under dask?

Comment: after doing `dd.read_hdf('myfile.*.hdf5', '/x')` you get a `dask.dataframe` object which contains this methods.

Comment: i recommend doing the learning notebook that the people at dask have created:
[datafrarme_notebook](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/dask/dask-examples/master?filepath=dataframe.ipynb).
after that you can use the dataframe documentation: [dataframe API](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html)